# Inconsistent number of questions for windows tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

On stackoverflow.com there seems to be a problem with displaying the number of question tagged with `windows`. If I type `[windows]` in the search box or click on the `windows` tag under a question tagged with windows only [two questions are returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows). On the other hand if I go to tags and in `Type to find tags:` enter windows I get this: [image: tags number of questions] again clicking on windows shows only two questions.
Why are these numbers inconsistent? This seems like a bug. I see some examples of questions tagged with windows that are not showing here.

EDIT: thanks to AnnaLear's comment: in fact clicking on stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows leads to the featured tab. Again this seems like a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be on the [Featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows?sort=featured) tab.

Switch to, say, [Newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows?sort=newest) and you'll see all of the questions.

Comment: Please press the url I have added in my question. It links to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows and points to featured tab. This seems to be wrong.

Comment: @izomorphius It's occasionally confusing, but that's how tabs work. The last one you visit persists. For you it took you to Featured. For me, it went to Newest. Try it out - go to the Newest tab for [tag:windows] and then visit a different tag.

Comment: you are right. That was the problem and it **is** confusing.